# Swift allows name collisions between protocol properties and conforming objects with properties of unrelated types

Tags: swift, swift4

Found a scenario where I would expect a name and/or type collision to occur, but which goes through and compiles somehow.

An object with some property can conform to a protocol with a property of the same name and a different type when the protocol's version has a default value defined in an extension and the object conforms to the protocol via an (unrelated) extension.

See the following example:

```
import Foundation

protocol SomeProtocol {
    var someProperty: Int { get }
}

extension SomeProtocol {
    var someProperty: Int { return 3 }
}

struct Thing {
    var someProperty = "string cheese"
}

extension Thing: SomeProtocol {}

let thing = Thing()

print(thing.someProperty) // string cheese
print(thing.someProperty as Int) // 3
```

Note that overloading a property in Swift usually causes a compile-time error:

```
class Thing {
    var what: Int { return 3 }
    var what: String { return "three" }
}
```

Error reads as follows:

```
**Untitled 8.swift:4:6: note: 'what' previously declared here
        var what: Int { return 3 }**
```

Clearly it behaves as an overloaded function, but it doesn't seem like this behavior is intentional.

Submitted a ticket to bugs.swift.org but writing it out here to share the discovery and find out if I'm missing anything or making any flawed assumptions.

Comment: Except swift doesn't allow for overloaded properties like this.  Function overloading is a feature of the language.  It's a bug because in this instance, it does behave that way, when it should show an error instead.

Comment: @kid_x This looks like a bug but probably it is not. Computed properties are really just a syntactic sugar for 2 functions - a setter and a getter. And the authors of the language have to decide whether they want them to behave more like stored properties or more like functions. Therefore, there must be some inconsistencies. I would recommend to report that as a bug but it's possible it will be closed.

Comment: I already submitted a bug to swift.org. It’s definitely an inconsistency due to the implementation of computed properties under the hood as methods, but what is that if not a bug?  I’ll post whatever follow-up I get back from swift.org.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this looks like property-based overloading. Basically Swift allows stuff like this:

```swift
func compute() -> Int {
    return 42
}

func compute() -> String {
    return "Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything"
}
```

which can be called like this:

```swift
let number = compute() as Int // 42
let string = compute() as String // "Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything"
```

Now, the above is not possible with stored properties, as you can only have one stored name, however in the protocol extension the property is computed, so it doesn't violate the storage rules.

Comment: Function overloading is allowed.  If you tried to set up a class with a computed property overloaded with two definitions, you would get a compile-time error.

Comment: @kid_x, yes, method overloading yes, while property overloading not, at least not in the same class hierarchy. The question kinda found a workaround.